# Input FASTA file required after local BLAST database is built?

Tags: fasta, blast

I've downloaded a very large fasta file and have built a local BLAST database. I'm trying to maintain storage space and was wondering if the input fasta file can be deleted after the local BLAST database has been built?

Comment: I think that you can try just removing the file from where it is and try running the local BLAST, if it works delete it. (I would take notes of which file is and how was made)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the fasta file and the blast still ran fine. I was initially worried about deleting it as the fasta files are big. But I was able to find a small blast database to test it on. Thanks Llopis!